# JupyterLab - how to find out which python venv is my session running on?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I am running venv based kernel and I am getting trouble in returning a proper answer from `which python` statement from my **JupyterLab** notebook. When running this command from terminal where I have my venv activated it works (it returns a proper venv path `~/venvs/my_venv/bin/python`), but it does not work in the notebook.

!which python

returns the host path:
/usr/bin/python

I have already tried with `os.system()` and `subprocess`, but with no luck.
Does anyone know how to execute this command from the Jupyter notebook?

Comment: What is the value of `sys.executable`?

Comment: Yes - this is the path I was looking for: `/home/username/venvs/my_vev/bin/python36`. You can put it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are starting the virtual environment *inside* the notebook, so that process's `PATH` doesn't reflect the modifications made by the venv. Instead, you want the path of the kernel that's actually running: that's `sys.executable`.

Answer (score -1):

maybe it's because you are trying to run the command outside venv

try `source /path/to/venv/bin/active` first and then try `which python`